# CWRsync failing due to spaces in directory names

Tags: rsync, cwrsync

I'm having trouble rsyncing folders with spaces between the names between two servers.

I have researched this error online but many of the solutions deal with just one folder with spaces, my problem is that I have two subfolders with spaces in their names and none of the solutions work

E.g. on the server I have the directory:
c:/test folder/test er/test.txt

When I run the rsync.cmd on the client the following error appears in the rsyncd.log file on the server

```
2011/08/09 09:16:01 [440] connect from server(xxx.xx.xx.xx)
2011/08/09 09:16:01 [440] rsync: chdir /cygdrive/c/'test folder'/'test er' failed
: No such file or directory (2)
```

In the rsyncd.conf folder on the server I have the following:

```
[TESTER]
path = /cygdrive/c/"test folder"/"test er"
read only = true
transfer logging = yes
```

This isn't working, however the following does work:
Folder: c:/test folder/test.txt

with rsyncd.conf code:

```
[TESTER]
path = /cygdrive/c/"test folder"
read only = true
transfer logging = yes
```

i.e it works for only one directory with spaces but not two.
I know it's a syntax issue but I can figure out the syntax and I tried a lot of varioeties based on research online include backslashes() and x20 for the spaces

I'm using cwrsync and the server machine is:
MicroSoft windows server 2003 R2

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, the only thing I didn't try was to not have any quotations or backslashes at all on the names.

i.e.

```
[TESTER]
path = /cygdrive/c/"test folder"/"test er"
read only = true
transfer logging = yes
```

The above worked